# Crystal Reports and uploaded PDF Documents

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, printing

I have a system that builds up reports on incedents. This allows the users to fill in multiple web forms and upload PDF documents, jpeg images and tiff images.

I have a cystal report that prints of all the form data related to the incedent but cannot find a quick method of printing off all the data and the pdf documents with one click.

Firstly is it possible to make pdf documents and images part of a cyrstal report, I store the locaitons of these documents in a database.

Secondly if this is not possible could I script this action to print all these documents and the crystal report in one click. The documents would need to print on the client side.

The tecnologies I am using are asp.net2 and server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of crystal? More importantly, check if you have the image location formula (right-click picture -> picture tab -> Graphic Location formula)? I believe it is available on CR XI and up. If you have this, then you can set the path of your image using your db table. Otherwise you will have to "push" the image to the report by stuffing it in a dataset.

I'm not sure if you can display pdf in CR. I know you can insert -> OLE object and display a link to the pdf, but I can't get it to actually draw the pdf in a CR.

As far as printing with asp.net goes, I'm utterly clueless. My first guess would be to export the report as a pdf and combine it with the static pdfs and let them download that.

Comment: Thanks for this I will give it a go and see how it goes